# Use SUMIF and VLOOKUP functions together

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif, sumifs, vba

This is my problem:

```
Sheet 1 - Column A has "Item #" 
Sheet 2 - Column C has "Item #" 
Sheet 1 - Column E will have the formula 
Sheet 2 - Column G has "Item Qty" 
Sheet 2 - Column B has "Size"
```

What I want is to return sum of 'Item Qty' of a certain 'Item #' based on 'Size'.

If Sheet1(A2) has Item # 123 I would like it to find all 123 Item #s in Sheet2 and return the sum of all those numbers ONLY IF the "Size" column equals my criteria, let's say "Medium".

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!G:G,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!B:B,"Medium")
```

Above would be more flexible as:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$G:$G,Sheet2!$C:$C,Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$B:$B,Sheet1!E$1)
```

where E1 contains "Medium". Then it could be copied across (say under F1 etc containing "Large" ...) to add up quantities for Large ... sizes of the item in A2 (and copied down for a different `item #` in A3 of Sheet1).

Comment: That only seems to return one item, there could be multiple identical Item #s with different Quantities that are different sizes...but thank you for your input, maybe you can solve this for me, because I am close to crying...

Comment: I have created a PT before and yes it does work, I am trying to automate this using VBA and when I go the PT route I get hung up on 'how, when I run the macro the next day, do I delete existing PT and add another one in its place?' idk if you can help with that. I have recorded a macro and I can run it, and it creates the PT, but when I run it again, it keeps the same PT and adds another one, is there a 'replace existing PT' feature?

Comment: good point, i will try to go that route instead, thanks for the input